# Facebook Ads - value means

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

In the standard tracking for ads I want to implemet the "Purchased" as the name of the event. I need to implement it on my site. this could be the possible for it:

```
fbq('track', 'Purchase', {currency: 'USD', value: 0.50});
```

I don't know if that is the right code for it.
I would like to ask if what is the meaning of this :

> value: 0.50

Answer (score 1):

The `value` parameter should be the total value of the purchase, in the specified currency.

For example, if this `Purchase` event was for a subscription that cost $20, your event would be:

```
fbq('track', 'Purchase', {
  currency: 'USD',
  value: 20.00
})
```

You can read more about event parameters here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/facebook-pixel/v2.6#parameters

Comment: what if the product is being purchased and the status on the site is pending. is facebook charging me this also? @craigkochis